# Why is it called Hilbert's "basis" theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, soft-question, terminology, noetherian

The statement of the theorem doesn't seem to hint at any "basis" whatsoever, so why the "basis"?

The theorem:

> If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then $A[x]$ is also Noetherian.

Comment: I think it's old-fashioned terminology for a finite set of generators of an ideal in $A[X]$.  But there's Gröbner basis - so it's still used.

Comment: Please *search* for answers before posting questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque Noted for future. (I wasn't using [tags] in my search, and this made the relevant answer escape my search. Now learnt using it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context a "basis" for an ideal $I$ is a generating set. Indeed, if our ideal is $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ (say), then we know every element of our ideal can be written as $ax+by+cz$ for some ring elements $a,b,c$. Keep in mind that unlike the vector space case, there might be multiple ways to do this!

So then with this terminology in hand, we come to some natural questions: Which ideals of which rings actually *have* a (finite) basis? Moreover, are there some bases that are "nicer" than others? And if so, how can we find the nice ones? All of these are incredibly important for actually *doing computations* with ideals and rings. So anytime you want to solve a system of polynomials (a very common problem!) you want to know how to find a nice basis for the ideal corresponding to that system, provided one exists.

This was viewed as quite a difficult problem, but Hilbert came and showed that the qualitative solution is easy! Provided every ideal of the ring $R$ we start with has a basis (that is, provided $R$ is noetherian) then every ideal of $R[x]$ *also* has a basis! The question of a "nice basis" was eventually solved as well, and these are called [Gröbner Bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). We know how to find them in general, and they really do make computations easier! See, for instance, the excellent book *Using Algebraic Geometry* by Cox, Little, and O'Shea.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).